# Resharper (R#) 4.5 and MVC (1.0) solutions cause Visual Studio 2008 SP1 to crash on solution load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, resharper

Does anyone have the issue with Resharper where opening a solution with MVC projects causes Visual studio to close/crash? No Errors, no warning, just close.

To fix the problem, I have to delete the bin and obj folders from the MVC project directory which allows the solution to be opened again.

When the solution is loaded, sometimes opening a .aspx/ascx file will close visual studio too.

I've never lost any work from this other than the occasional mismatched project/file system.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening for me too (I also have PowerCommands and R# 4.5).

This question has quite a few different suggestions you could try: [500696 - why-does-visual-studio-crash-opening-aspx-with-mvc-rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500696/why-does-visual-studio-crash-opening-aspx-with-mvc-rc1)

I basically followed the steps outlined by Steve Mason by doing a 'Clean' of my solution and the ngen update step.

I seem to be OK for now (fingers crossed)...

Comment: Hey! the ngen step felt like it did something. Whatever it did it improved performance of opening aspx/ascx. Not sure yet if it's solved my crash issue (as it was somewhat unpredictable), but this is definitely the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

Which version of R# are you using? I suggest

1. first trying it out with the latest official R# version
2. if that doesn't help, try with some of the [R# nightly builds](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+4.5+Nightly+Builds)

R# can be unstable, in general - I've downloaded the latest official version yesterday and it constantly reports exceptions (not fatal ones though). The latest nightly build seems to be more stable.

Comment: 4.5 - i think i'm using the latest

Answer (score 1):

Have you got PowerCommands installed? Try uninstalling/disabling and see if everything works.
In fact, try this for each of your VS addins.

Comment: Is PowerTools a Visual studio plugin or windows app?

Comment: whoops i meant http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands

I came across a VS bug aages ago where it jumped out of the app that was caused by a combination of PowerCommands and the order of something in the web.config. Good times.

Comment: I don't have PowerCommands, and I've narrowed it down (by disabling each addin) to R# 4.5. R# is definitely the culprit